# Generate unique ID CSV list from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I am trying to get a unique list of IDs from a table in CSV format. I am close I just need to be able to remove duplicates. So far I have:

```
DECLARE @csv VARCHAR(max)

set @csv = null
SELECT @csv = COALESCE(@csv + ',', '') + ''''+ID+''''
FROM TABLE

select @csv
```

The only problem is the table can have multiple IDs, and I only want each occurrence once. I tried adding a "DISTINCT" before the ID but it doesn't like being there.

Answer (score 0):

Using the syntax `SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM` is a [documented antipattern](//learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your data in a row by row order, which there is *no* guarentee of. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using `STRING_AGG`, however, in older versions you'll need to use `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) to achieve the same results.

Assuming you are on a fully supported version of SQL Server, then use a CTE/derived table to get the `DISTINCT` values, and then aggregate that:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT ID
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT STRING_AGG(ID,',')
FROM CTE;
```